# How to loop over individuals and time in panel data?

Tags: r, for-loop, panel-data

Assume I have the following data frame where T denotes the number of time observations:

```
T = 5 * 52

t <- runif(T, 0, 30000)
d <- runif(T, 0, 20000)
o <- runif(T, 0, 20000)

mediaspend <- data.frame(t, d, o)
```

Now I can easily run the following loop:

```
lambda <- c(0.90, 0.80, 0.70)

adstock <- matrix(NA, ncol = 3, nrow = T)
for (i in 1:3){
  adstock[1,i] <- (1-lambda[i]) * log(mediaspend[1,i])
  for (j in 2:T){
  adstock[j,i] <- lambda[i] * adstock[j-1,i] + (1-lambda[i]) * log(mediaspend[j,i])
  }
}
```

But I'm really struggling with running the same loop considering panel data. Assume my data now looks like the following and I observe the time series for 20 subjects (e.g. companies).

```
N = 20
T = 5 * 52

t <- runif(N*T, 0, 30000)
d <- runif(N*T, 0, 20000)
o <- runif(N*T, 0, 20000)

mediaspend <- data.frame(t, d, o)
```

My approach is to convert the data frame into a list consisting of N data frames, looping over the list elements, saving the results into a new list and finally convert that list into a data frame again.

```
lambda <- c(0.90, 0.80, 0.70)

mediaspend_list <- split(mediaspend, f = rep(1:N, each=T))
adstock_list <- list()
adstock_temp <- matrix(NA, nrow = T, ncol = 3)

for (n in 1:N){
  for (i in 1:3){
    adstock_temp[1,i] <- (1-lambda[i]) * log(mediaspend_list[[n]][1,i])
    for (j in 2:T){
      adstock_temp[j,i] <- lambda[i] * adstock_temp[j-1,i] + (1-lambda[i]) * log(mediaspend_list[[n]][j,i])
    }
  } 
  adstock_list[[n]] <- adstock_temp
}
adstock <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, adstock_list)
```

Is there any way to directly loop over the whole panel without converting the original data frame into a list, using grouping etc.? Only by using mediaspend and the information about its structure in terms of N and T.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem gradually. First, define a function that could give you the result you want for a single vector and a single lambda. Something like this

```
fadstock <- function(x, lambda) {
  Reduce(
    function(stock, logx) (1 - lambda) * logx + lambda * stock, 
    log(x), init = 0, accumulate = TRUE
  )[-1L] # remove the init zero
}
```

Then we give this function the ability to be used by groups. This can be done by combining this function and `ave`. We will specify our grouping variables in `...`.

```
fadstockby <- function(x, lambda, ...) {
  ave(x, ..., FUN = function(i) fadstock(i, lambda))
}
```

Now just apply it to your dataframe.

```
set.seed(123L) 
N <- 20
T <- 5 * 52
lambda <- c(0.90, 0.80, 0.70)
mediaspend <- data.frame(
  t = runif(N*T, 0, 30000),
  d = runif(N*T, 0, 20000),
  o = runif(N*T, 0, 20000)
)

mapply(fadstockby, mediaspend, lambda, MoreArgs = list(rep(1:N, each = T)))
```

Output

```
                t        d        o
   [1,] 0.9062690 1.969970 2.924830
   [2,] 1.8227503 3.331274 4.756824
   [3,] 2.5819609 4.301262 6.021698
   [4,] 3.3422191 5.042083 5.984246
   [5,] 4.0327546 5.581179 7.109135
   [6,] 4.3514942 6.295179 7.834688
   [7,] 4.8833941 6.975016 7.089645
   [8,] 5.4145680 7.532108 7.897926
   [9,] 5.8444834 7.458782 7.923456
  [10,] 6.2125388 7.885316 8.333030
  [11,] 6.6177675 8.283409 8.629500
  [12,] 6.9077735 8.373908 8.929832
  [13,] 7.2089673 8.613116 8.865494
  [14,] 7.4632148 8.767419 8.659802
  [15,] 7.5204128 8.366168 7.362317
  [16,] 7.7887113 8.513546 8.080683
  [17,] 7.9005287 8.701863 8.147372
  [18,] 7.8245042 8.897728 8.455535
  [19,] 7.9614507 8.976339 8.873499
  [20,] 8.1915445 9.136615 9.017800
  [21,] 8.3915802 8.291401 8.630387
  [22,] 8.5466165 8.452701 8.819810
  [23,] 8.6783006 8.597437 8.974319
  [24,] 8.8407911 8.812329 9.137071
  [25,] 8.9454030 8.774903 9.016307
  [26,] 9.0473017 8.895280 9.168300
  [27,] 9.1125983 8.762083 9.185265
  [28,] 9.1801701 8.947548 9.333102
  [29,] 9.1689707 9.034674 9.250755
  [30,] 9.0913139 8.948296 9.376570
  [31,] 9.2093101 9.095351 9.292377
  [32,] 9.3089935 9.156442 9.457273
  [33,] 9.3719852 9.297252 9.352416
  [34,] 9.4427994 9.073988 9.438493
  [35,] 9.1589694 8.147149 8.312845
  [36,] 9.2001106 8.300516 8.575863
  [37,] 9.2833482 8.569212 8.766340
  [38,] 9.2328497 8.724738 8.034433
  [39,] 9.2259465 8.606636 8.416379
  [40,] 9.1879839 8.383069 8.678493
  [41,] 9.1054498 8.660727 8.921316
  [42,] 9.1377430 8.523897 8.390650
  [43,] 9.1666084 8.709076 8.817597
  [44,] 9.1811051 8.786578 9.096818
  [45,] 9.1057945 8.994533 9.139545
  [46,] 9.0286426 9.078086 8.786647
  [47,] 9.0110166 8.708637 8.971791
  [48,] 9.0644451 8.815590 8.897838
  [49,] 9.0564597 8.958832 8.429159
  [50,] 9.1663738 9.003003 8.815165
  [51,] 8.9723526 9.086219 8.956616
  [52,] 9.0244133 9.102514 8.709538
  [53,] 9.1304184 9.230827 8.223296
  [54,] 9.0378158 9.101751 8.627005
  [55,] 9.1071168 9.083090 9.003021
  [56,] 9.0695701 9.202445 8.607538
  [57,] 8.9875693 9.315648 8.690275
  [58,] 9.0913795 9.309569 8.300164
  [59,] 9.2020487 9.205511 8.646167
  [60,] 9.2145128 9.235570 8.939524
  [61,] 9.2831773 9.149756 9.108800
  [62,] 9.1501991 8.932097 9.239234
  [63,] 9.1703553 8.991754 8.733993
  [64,] 9.1548922 8.511865 8.896664
  [65,] 9.2497974 8.400476 9.082883
  [66,] 9.2755319 8.348942 8.829558
  [67,] 9.3578098 8.434442 8.565435
  [68,] 9.4321466 8.520318 8.830712
  [69,] 9.4968031 8.768293 9.035389
  [70,] 9.4958817 8.789014 9.254337
  [71,] 9.5490155 9.001801 9.054077
  [72,] 9.5786820 9.036351 9.061078
  [73,] 9.6174857 9.181331 8.895832
  [74,] 8.9488202 9.096384 9.124442
  [75,] 9.0104561 9.039359 9.233791
  [76,] 8.9889470 8.847414 9.368372
  [77,] 9.0241409 8.964609 9.396413
  [78,] 9.1036456 8.813177 9.334566
  [79,] 9.1197065 8.907716 9.231640
  [80,] 9.0189305 8.781117 9.273559
  [81,] 9.0067180 8.552938 9.022631
  [82,] 9.0966030 8.601475 8.960718
  [83,] 9.1305261 8.760235 9.078531
  [84,] 9.2245679 8.914791 8.912016
  [85,] 9.1055722 8.795470 8.989615
  [86,] 9.1426447 8.841191 8.980008
  [87,] 9.2577597 8.666659 9.201640
  [88,] 9.3515679 8.599555 8.194203
  [89,] 9.4352555 8.807008 8.307067
  [90,] 9.3483583 8.880187 8.626163
  [91,] 9.2409294 8.799002 8.770492
  [92,] 9.3051295 8.974368 9.074657
  [93,] 9.2986598 8.997234 9.319812
  [94,] 9.3576452 8.824034 9.388447
  [95,] 9.3389490 8.679683 8.850938
  [96,] 9.2686536 8.918073 9.144380
  [97,] 9.3481311 8.985256 9.230858
  [98,] 9.2073354 9.039089 9.222014
  [99,] 9.2413072 9.137397 9.301499
 [100,] 9.2810321 9.242984 8.377654
 [101,] 9.3327397 9.301554 8.499841
 [102,] 9.3203467 9.396245 8.564086
 [103,] 9.3475889 9.106078 8.536460
 [104,] 9.4390658 9.000140 8.569448
 [105,] 9.4532604 9.158804 8.182533
 [106,] 9.5272156 9.099999 8.644507
 [107,] 9.5964447 9.246672 8.257480
 [108,] 9.6180583 9.154552 8.658073
 [109,] 9.5981560 9.216760 8.753706
 [110,] 9.4775678 9.223836 9.084548
 [111,] 9.5540175 9.244717 9.296903
 [112,] 9.5095225 9.237366 9.192768
 [113,] 9.3093183 9.243926 9.210622
 [114,] 9.4039128 9.183966 9.349681
 [115,] 9.4616492 9.226245 9.496914
 [116,] 9.3513937 9.094710 9.317675
 [117,] 9.3872358 9.169291 9.104492
 [118,] 9.4747079 9.234854 8.967105
 [119,] 9.5046006 9.250612 9.148872
 [120,] 9.4945280 9.145794 9.250141
 [121,] 9.5325676 9.238025 9.266521
 [122,] 9.4962066 9.337918 8.977225
 [123,] 9.4596247 9.251381 9.121952
 [124,] 9.3930390 9.218171 9.310399
 [125,] 9.3850669 9.327525 9.325616
 [126,] 9.4758648 9.263835 9.364560
 [127,] 9.3722246 9.247032 9.452328
 [128,] 9.2262562 9.241173 9.343524
 [129,] 9.1392674 8.727701 9.301713
 [130,] 9.2191306 8.777228 9.044589
 [131,] 9.2801893 8.847297 9.247659
 [132,] 9.3715687 8.941472 8.887893
 [133,] 9.4257060 9.054545 9.080380
 [134,] 9.4835245 9.147870 7.820049
 [135,] 9.5008928 9.275835 8.234845
 [136,] 9.5401228 9.320083 8.636163
 [137,] 9.5973806 9.307514 8.780183
 [138,] 9.6444938 9.193134 8.814819
 [139,] 9.7089012 8.606696 8.453210
 [140,] 9.6866790 8.458074 8.496969
 [141,] 9.6323357 8.609297 8.512832
 [142,] 9.6107094 8.733828 8.877793
 [143,] 9.2245820 8.535582 8.907718
 [144,] 9.1636553 8.536752 9.203562
 [145,] 9.2610741 8.449138 9.355926
 [146,] 9.2193982 8.484983 9.304984
 [147,] 9.1852663 8.392610 9.412151
 [148,] 9.0408381 8.525483 9.394451
 [149,] 9.0272948 8.490925 9.079028
 [150,] 9.1242815 8.263217 9.261554
 [151,] 9.2261967 8.563937 9.109404
 [152,] 9.2646618 8.523657 9.331318
 [153,] 9.2743924 8.480553 9.490353
 [154,] 9.2377884 8.535088 9.457625
 [155,] 9.1251692 8.587222 8.829507
 [156,] 9.1493853 8.798002 8.927043
 [157,] 9.2094691 8.907746 9.051955
 [158,] 9.1665822 8.743009 9.121743
 [159,] 9.1997990 8.933790 9.207663
 [160,] 9.1583841 9.111481 9.248542
 [161,] 9.2045851 8.994598 9.091669
 [162,] 9.2111490 9.119221 9.200767
 [163,] 9.2778488 8.958479 8.671895
 [164,] 9.2828000 9.110032 8.612093
 [165,] 9.2819769 9.029267 8.681955
 [166,] 9.3218801 9.150955 8.772852
 [167,] 9.3905220 8.878498 9.110964
 [168,] 9.3314524 9.049730 8.401425
 [169,] 9.3407101 9.181089 8.616661
 [170,] 9.3049906 9.293978 8.739429
 [171,] 9.3591790 8.569934 8.822424
 [172,] 9.2847812 8.182221 8.790468
 [173,] 9.3725389 8.284916 8.956356
 [174,] 9.4369534 8.384882 9.170668
 [175,] 9.4838492 8.169942 8.757516
 [176,] 9.5182358 8.447612 8.881055
 [177,] 9.4984853 8.002497 9.110826
 [178,] 9.5160132 8.343993 8.819660
 [179,] 9.5819177 8.521783 9.064072
 [180,] 9.6004498 8.744994 8.951870
 [181,] 9.6538371 8.963893 8.934064
 [182,] 9.6030169 9.029300 8.924078
 [183,] 9.6391204 9.193655 9.023825
 [184,] 9.5733078 9.105816 8.695747
 [185,] 9.5948424 9.015552 8.703568
 [186,] 9.5931249 9.186713 9.010942
 [187,] 9.5319175 9.047059 9.194342
 [188,] 9.5524555 9.173650 9.250772
 [189,] 9.6190239 9.075604 8.539225
 [190,] 9.6776888 9.168925 8.829420
 [191,] 9.6114132 9.261261 8.885664
 [192,] 9.5676861 9.130584 8.335691
 [193,] 9.6403664 8.233657 8.713050
 [194,] 9.6594204 8.395121 8.407874
 [195,] 9.7178999 8.593900 8.842503
 [196,] 9.7007625 8.692604 8.792339
 [197,] 9.6716461 8.720507 8.614240
 [198,] 9.6937086 8.825024 8.967909
 [199,] 9.5670733 8.745435 8.640301
 [200,] 9.5855510 8.729070 8.708611
 [201,] 9.5146473 8.204409 8.832096
 [202,] 9.5902411 8.416632 9.113117
 [203,] 9.6112570 8.539770 9.128198
 [204,] 9.6146735 8.807408 9.249983
 [205,] 9.5931137 8.425742 9.369871
 [206,] 9.6519422 8.631565 9.276074
 [207,] 9.6166084 8.744862 9.227708
 [208,] 9.5614464 7.904815 9.003258
 [209,] 9.4593801 7.967523 8.894611
 [210,] 9.3684111 8.263654 9.169865
 [211,] 9.3894930 8.460247 9.381005
 [212,] 9.3439885 8.725965 9.441517
 [213,] 9.2873551 8.883631 9.282659
 [214,] 9.3501182 8.954405 9.255101
 [215,] 9.1416430 8.908185 9.386700
 [216,] 9.2228282 8.922678 9.367290
 [217,] 9.2269966 8.743763 9.450397
 [218,] 9.2457745 8.782091 9.190735
 [219,] 9.3323632 8.744765 9.072018
 [220,] 9.4215597 8.965257 9.311994
 [221,] 9.3839014 8.877445 9.474618
 [222,] 9.4724393 9.021275 9.505352
 [223,] 9.5243994 8.659132 8.998264
 [224,] 9.5652216 8.709590 9.209459
 [225,] 9.3455535 8.643270 8.893384
 [226,] 9.3490622 8.869516 8.645930
 [227,] 9.3712044 8.904385 8.984308
 [228,] 9.4070426 8.876965 8.416930
 [229,] 9.4613175 8.905219 8.017274
 [230,] 9.5372725 8.733800 8.575673
 [231,] 9.5663707 8.875053 8.882896
 [232,] 9.5558641 9.028310 8.997544
 [233,] 9.5699389 9.182673 9.105009
 [234,] 9.3599306 9.228026 8.975637
 [235,] 9.3204545 9.270929 9.175656
 [236,] 9.3269607 9.314962 9.168692
 [237,] 9.2630820 9.418153 9.315639
 [238,] 9.3492681 9.513663 9.145736
 [239,] 9.2574311 9.321069 8.960573
 [240,] 9.3406953 9.190558 9.193961
 [241,] 9.3771586 9.314633 8.987132
 [242,] 9.4291370 9.235333 9.180048
 [243,] 9.3409170 9.304246 9.327221
 [244,] 9.3920009 9.389217 9.496747
 [245,] 9.3671791 9.062420 9.556600
 [246,] 9.4291366 9.196842 8.934892
 [247,] 9.4252237 9.253920 8.619594
 [248,] 9.5104843 8.447869 8.704528
 [249,] 9.5870167 8.293711 8.399280
 [250,] 9.6272865 8.445550 8.738906
 [251,] 9.5596695 8.699447 8.501142
 [252,] 9.4839944 8.721690 8.906963
 [253,] 9.5142419 8.713680 8.994417
 [254,] 9.4618574 8.932069 8.706601
 [255,] 9.4832808 8.946404 8.852639
 [256,] 9.5416780 9.024572 8.964779
 [257,] 9.4400625 8.921811 9.243386
 [258,] 9.4364163 8.716560 9.123688
 [259,] 9.4485025 8.629094 9.252576
 [260,] 9.5204034 8.757040 8.592598
 [261,] 1.0231756 1.971622 2.724762
 [262,] 1.9391945 3.384480 4.291566
 [263,] 2.7367455 4.653257 5.612718
 [264,] 3.4888544 5.197403 6.264226
 [265,] 4.1047856 6.081145 6.991095
 [266,] 4.6701276 6.580815 6.870457
 [267,] 5.1250442 7.118126 7.384967
 [268,] 5.5376855 7.055297 7.983742
 [269,] 5.6237314 7.572464 7.963214
 [270,] 6.0234998 8.019922 8.373844
 [271,] 6.4382388 8.338009 8.663769
 [272,] 6.3186020 8.185343 8.956236
 [273,] 6.4546075 8.517783 7.066758
 [274,] 6.6593818 8.450322 7.884675
 [275,] 6.9982458 8.696913 7.857007
 [276,] 7.2985531 8.858510 7.375848
 [277,] 7.5967403 8.893205 8.081582
 [278,] 7.7917059 9.038658 8.303105
 [279,] 7.7835798 9.035693 8.608899
 [280,] 7.9928568 9.105087 8.393505
 [281,] 8.1968374 9.036797 8.743933
 [282,] 8.2093489 9.122893 8.918981
 [283,] 8.3268227 9.073582 8.829968
 [284,] 8.3758637 9.212135 9.098760
 [285,] 8.2843699 9.170347 9.315381
 [286,] 8.3941670 9.159848 9.361188
 [287,] 8.3121984 9.285115 9.236012
 [288,] 8.3631015 9.323272 9.207974
 [289,] 8.2669678 8.517209 9.318708
 [290,] 8.4311606 8.710011 9.187026
 [291,] 8.4977869 8.664436 9.197276
 [292,] 8.4493640 8.905235 9.212211
 [293,] 8.3720807 8.943910 9.305683
 [294,] 8.5530346 9.055321 9.419304
 [295,] 8.7004229 8.763838 9.231453
 [296,] 8.8410160 8.676495 9.372861
 [297,] 8.9860076 8.911063 9.498183
 [298,] 8.8915799 8.996432 9.492011
 [299,] 8.8020959 8.998307 9.256610
 [300,] 8.9303211 9.070327 9.408199
 [301,] 9.0439230 8.831991 9.556149
 [302,] 8.7040390 8.906846 9.464267
 [303,] 8.8395644 8.770095 9.346834
 [304,] 8.9549486 8.711764 9.491740
 [305,] 9.0441664 8.907595 9.436013
 [306,] 9.0974377 9.029216 9.023119
 [307,] 9.0332067 9.197811 8.891731
 [308,] 8.6806083 8.943486 9.045885
 [309,] 8.7641368 8.976030 9.224066
 [310,] 8.8477503 9.018676 8.420865
 [311,] 8.8996037 9.073368 8.699587
 [312,] 8.9638950 9.082485 8.945095
 [313,] 9.0646125 8.893968 9.141223
 [314,] 8.8995518 9.028733 7.949179
 [315,] 8.9368670 9.183945 8.453980
 [316,] 9.0521121 9.080478 8.604628
 [317,] 9.1598487 9.191519 8.541381
 [318,] 9.1311053 9.319305 8.760310
 [319,] 9.1450402 8.513558 9.034651
 [320,] 9.2459864 8.653107 9.185407
 [321,] 9.3364729 8.633297 8.757273
 [322,] 9.3119459 8.732956 8.714852
 [323,] 9.2199472 8.787494 8.898002
 [324,] 9.2937489 8.974702 8.824747
 [325,] 9.1687468 8.758321 9.088570
 [326,] 8.9438240 8.959394 9.136426
 [327,] 9.0802773 8.961088 8.500495
 [328,] 8.8675458 9.053964 8.543560
 [329,] 8.9033313 8.813526 8.618450
 [330,] 9.0350172 9.006332 8.889631
 [331,] 9.1141603 9.096605 8.873208
 [332,] 9.1085629 9.124092 9.078166
 [333,] 9.1981933 9.188018 8.145933
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 4867 rows ]
```